# Display text vertically using XDrawString

Tags: c, linux, xlib, motif

I am using **XDrawString** to display text on a drawing area. By default this seems to display text horizontally from Left to Right.

Could any one please tell me how I can use this library function to rotate and display text vertically from Top to Bottom or from Bottom to top.

Thanks in advance for you help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call it once per character, there's no single function that can draw a rotated string in Xlib. [Here's a quote from the Programming Manual](http://www.sbin.org/doc/Xlib/chapt_06.html):

> Vertical Text and Rotated Text
>
> Xlib provides routines that draw horizontal strings, but not vertical ones. If you want to draw strings vertically that read normally, you need to use a separate text drawing call for each character. You use a baseline with the same x coordinate but a different y coordinate for each character.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. On another note, is it possible to rotate text using the  Xlib library?

Comment: Use XRender - you can set any 2x2 transformation matrix for compositing operations